# Testing workflow using parameterized test or separate test

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, integration-testing

How to test workflow - using separate test or parameterized test ?

I have workflow like this

A -> B -> c -> D -> E -->Z

User can skip any step between A and Z but not A and Z.

If I have to write test case shoud we write separate test case or parameterized test

if I write separate test I have to write four tests but with parameterized one less code.

I have tried parameterized test, as there are if statement in asserts it becomes less readable.

```
A = WorkflowStep('A')
B = WorkflowStep('B')
C = WorkflowStep('C')
D = WorkflowStep('D')
E = WorkflowStep('E')
Z = WorkflowStep('Z')


@pytest.mark.parametrize('skipStep', [([B]), ([C]), ([D]), ([E])])
test_skip_step(skipStep):
    workflow = Workflow.create().skip(skipStep);
    summary = workflow.goTo(Z)

    if skipStep != B:
       summary.hasB()
    if skipStep != C:
       summary.hasC()
    if skipStep != D:
       summary.hasD()
    if skipStep != E:
       summary.hasE()
```

What approach I should take?
 - Write separate test to test skipping each step?
 - Write parameterized test ?

Comment: Please consider removing one tag: either this is Unit Testing or is Integration Testing. I'd leave only testing as tag, personally.

Answer (score 2):

Taking into consideration the requirements you provided, if I were to write a test case, I would write the following:

- A test case scenario to check that User can't skip steps (two test cases);
- A test case scenario to check the User can skip steps (four test cases?);
- A test case scenario to ensure that workflow flows like you stated (n test cases);

But, to answer your question, depends on the test strategy your company will approve. Factors like the criticality of the unit you are testing must be taken into consideration. In the end, I'd go with a parametrized approach, but not one that has hardcoded cases into it.

If you can truly parametrize each step, then you should not see any switch case inside of the function. If you cannot, then go for separate functions, as it is reasonable to expect that mainteneance for each of them will require different actions.

Bottom line: go for something that you can maintain easily, and, if you have time, write more test cases than the ones you will execute.
Finally remember, you are coding for humans, so readability is a nice feature.

Comment: Agree - there should not be conditional assert in unit test

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to perform all these tests, then a parameterized approach makes sense to avoid a maintenance issue for the large set of similarly implemented test cases.  I propose to change the summary interface from `hasB`, `hasC`, ... to: `hasStep(step)`.  Then you can generalize your tests better.

```
skippableSteps = [B, C, D, E]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('skipStep', [([B]), ([C]), ([D]), ([E])])
def test_skip_forOneStepOfBCDE_leavesOtherStepsIn(skipstep)
    workflow = Workflow.create()
    workflow.skip(skipStep).goTo(Z)
    expectedSteps = skippableSteps[:].remove(skipstep)
    for step in expectedSteps:
        assert summary.hasStep(step)
```

Comment: I like the approach but if we restructure code it can become more testable and readable

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is there should not be if-else statements in the test cases to assert. It makes the call for a separate test for maintainability and readability.

May be reverse thing could help build workflow using steps which need to be present then test they are there. Also, assert on count so that unwanted steps should seep into.

```
A = WorkflowStep('A')
B = WorkflowStep('B')
C = WorkflowStep('C')
D = WorkflowStep('D')
E = WorkflowStep('E')
Z = WorkflowStep('Z')


@pytest.mark.parametrize('includedSteps', [(['A','C','D','E','Z']), (['A','B','D','E','Z']), (['A','B','C','E','Z']), (['A','B', 'C','D','Z'])])
test_skip_step(includedSteps):
    workflow = Workflow.build(includedSteps);
    summary = workflow.goTo(Z)

   // To ensure encluded steps
    step in includedSteps:
        assert summary.hasStep(step)

    // To avoid unwanted steps
    assert summary.stepsCnt == len(includedSteps)
```